# Runtime for algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I need to get the asymptotic runtime for an algorithm and I'm just stuck.

[image: Algorithm]

A python implementation:

```py
def alg3(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, n+1):
            k = j
            while k <= n:
                k = k*3
```

I think it should somehow be $\Theta(n^2\log(n))$ but that isn't quadratic. 
Can you help?

```py
import time

def alg3(n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, n+1):
            k = j
            while k <= n:
                count = count + 1
                k = k*3
    print(count)

n = 10
for i in range(0, 6):
    start_time = time.time()
    # run two times then calculate average time
    for i in range(0, 100):
        alg3(n)
    print("time with size %s: %s seconds" % (n, (time.time() - start_time)/100))
    n = n*2
```

If you calculate the factors given they give about 4.1.

Comment: Have you tried it with n such that {there exists a positive integer m such that ​ 3^m ≤ n ​ and 3^m doesn't fit in a [machine word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture))}$\hspace{.02 in}$? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: 1) Please transcribe the algorithm using Markdown. 2) Experiments can never prove asymptotics. 3) Our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) can help you do the analysis.

Comment: What is the question here? "Can you help?" is too broad a query. Community votes, please!

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(n) = n^2\log n$, with the $\log$ taken to base 2. Then
$$
\frac{f(2n)}{f(n)} = 4 \frac{\log(2n)}{\log n} = 4 \left(1 + \frac{1}{\log n}\right).
$$
That is, for large $n$ you would expect $f(2n) \approx 4f(n)$. This shows that this test isn't sensitive enough to detect logarithmic factors.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f$ be the runtime of your algorithm, it's easy to find a close form
$$
  f(n) = n \sum_{j=1}^n \log_3 \left\lceil \frac{n}{j}\right\rceil
$$

Then some calculations,
$$
\begin{aligned}
  f(n) &\leq n + \frac1{\ln 3} n \sum_{j=1}^n \ln (\frac{n}{j}) \\
  &\leq n + \frac1{\ln 3} n \int_{0}^{n} \ln (\frac{n}{x}) \mathrm{d}x \\
  &= n + \frac1{\ln 3} n^2
\end{aligned}
$$

Similarly, you can lower bound $f$.

$f(n) = \frac1{\ln 3} n^2 + O(n)$.